# Is there a way to insert circle with algebraic coordinate into an arrangement?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, cgal, motion-planning

I am working on a motion planning problem and I'm facing problems with numeric precision.

My goal is to divide the two-dimensional vector space of real numbers with segments and circular arcs. The [2D Arrangement of the CGAL library](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html) is well indicated for this purpose. Here are the types I have defined:

```
typedef CGAL::CORE_algebraic_number_traits Nt_traits;
typedef Nt_traits::Rational Rational;
typedef Nt_traits::Algebraic Algebraic;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Rational> Rat_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Algebraic> Alg_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Arr_conic_traits_2<Rat_kernel, Alg_kernel, Nt_traits> Conic_traits_2;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Conic_traits_2> Arrangement_2;
```

During the computation I need to displaced a segment whose endpoints have rational coordinates, (due to the length of the segment, i.e. square root,) the image of this segment then have algebraic coordinates. I also need to add two circular arcs to the endpoints of this image.

All I have found in the manual is a way to add circular arcs with rational coordinates for the center, how to treat those with algebraic coordinates (without precision error) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to subdivide the plane with linear segments and circular arcs exploiting CGAL arrangements is to use the `CGAL::Arr_circle_segment_traits_2` traits. As the manual says, it should be instantiated with a rational kernel (a kernel defined with an exact rational number type). However, the `Point_2` type nested in the traits class is different than the `Kernel::Point_2` type. Its coordinates are an instantiation of `CGAL::Sqrt_extension`. This special number type is much more efficient than a standard algebraic number type. If you must use a (standard) algebraic number type for some reason, then you can use the `CGAL::Arr_algebraic_segment_traits_2` traits. The latter supports any general algebraic curve.

Comment: The reason why I use `CGAL::Arr_conic_traits_2` instead of `CGAL::Arr_circle_segment_traits_2` is that the subdivision of the plane is based on an inset polygon which type is `CGAL::Gps_traits_2<Conic_traits_2>::Polygon_2`. Then changing the traits class used by the program is not a solution.

Comment: Well, why not use CGAL::Gps_traits_2<CGAL::Arr_circle_segment_traits_2>::Polygon_2? The traits determines the number type. It is a purpose, a reason, and a goal...

Comment: The use of `Gps_traits_2<Arr_circle_segment_traits_2>::Polygon_2` needs a conversion from `Gps_traits_2<Arr_conic_traits_2>::Polygon_2` (i.e. type result of an inset). That is possible, however my division of the two-dimensional space of real numbers is not a general polygon but a set of general polygons which might share some common edges. That is why the `Gps_traits_2<Arr_circle_segment_traits_2>::Polygon_2` is too high level, then I can use the underlying type `Arrangement_2<Arr_circle_segment_traits_2>` but this does not allow me to deal with circle with algebraic coordinate.

Comment: Let's go back one step for a second. Have you considered using CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2 to compute the inset? If this is an option, look at the example of ex_approx_offset.cpp in our book, namely, CGAL Arrangements and Their Applications. It's listed in Chapter 9, and the code can be obtained from our Web Page http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/cgal-arrangement-book/source-code-data-and-miscellaneous-files

Comment: Yes I have considered to use the `approximated_inset_2` function (see [2D Minkowski Sums](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/index.html#title7)). However, for some reasons, I need to get an inset with angles between two arcs less than 180° (in its interior). Unfortunately the approximation do not give me this property.

Comment: It would be great if the `exact_inset` function requires an instance of an arrangement-traits class that is capable of handling segments and circle in an exact manner. But what about circle with algebraic coordinate ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and as I understand [the section of the CGAL manual about it](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html#title42), there is no traits class to deal with circular arcs with algebraic coordinates.

(I will forward your question to CGAL developers to be sure. I will edit my answer once I know more.)